# Do Master Career Rewards stay after leaving the career track?

Tags: the-sims-3

If I switch careers will I lose the "Special Ability"?

For instance Professional Sports allows you to do Autograph Signings.  If I become an Astronaut do I lose the ability?

Another side question, I've heard that as a DNA specialist you get a cool laptop. If I leave the career track do they repo the laptop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You keep items, such as the limo, the fridge, and the laptop.

You keep hidden traits (and the actions they enable), such as the ability to salute.

You lose job functions, such as the ability to hold meetings and autograph sessions.